# angularjs form submiting with ng-model

Tags: html, controller, submit

I'm new to angularjs, so i'm having some difficulties submiting a form. i can get my form  information as JSON in my page but when i'm trying to show them in console no object is being created. this is part of my html.

```
<html lang="en" ng-app='eventApp'>
  <form class="form-inline" role="form" ng-submit='submitForm(eventForm)'>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="begin_freq" ng-model='eventForm.freqb'>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="end_freq" ng-model='eventForm.freqe'>
      <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-success">submit</button>
  <form>
<html>
```

and this is my controller :

```
angular.module('eventApp',[])
.controller('formCntrl',function($scope){
    $scope.event=[];
    console.log($scope.event);
    $scope.submitForm= function(form) {
        $scope.event.push(form);
        console.log($scope.event);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the way to print complete object

```
 for (var key in $scope.event[0])
        {
            console.log($scope.event[0][key]);
        }
```

Comment: thank you for your immediate answer, but no. i had problem with the ng-controller placement in the html tags. now i have an object with my data from form in it. again